# Check if an element is a child of a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="hello">Hello <div>Child-Of-Hello</div></div>
<br />
<div id="goodbye">Goodbye <div>Child-Of-Goodbye</div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function fun(evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);    
    if ($('div#hello').parents(target).length) {
        alert('Your clicked element is having div#hello as parent');
    }
}
$(document).bind('click', fun);
-->
</script>

</html>
```

I expect only when `Child-Of-Hello` being clicked, `$('div#hello').parents(target).length` will return >0.

However, it just happen whenever I click on anywhere.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

If you are only interested in the direct parent, and not other ancestors, you can just use `parent()`, and give it the selector, as in `target.parent('div#hello')`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6BX9n/

```
function fun(evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);    
    if (target.parent('div#hello').length) {
        alert('Your clicked element is having div#hello as parent');
    }
}
```

Or if you want to check to see if there are any ancestors that match, then use `.parents()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6BX9n/1/

```
function fun(evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);    
    if (target.parents('div#hello').length) {
        alert('Your clicked element is having div#hello as parent');
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do it without jquery?

Answer (score 80):

[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) seems to be designed for this purpose. Since it returns a jQuery object, you have to test for `.length` as well:

```
if ($('div#hello').has(target).length) {
   alert('Target is a child of #hello');
}
```

Comment: @redanimalwar Right; that's what this does. You find the parent element, then check if `target` is inside of it.

Answer (score 36):

Vanilla 1-liner for IE8+:

```
parent !== child && parent.contains(child);
```

Here, how it works:

```js
function contains(parent, child) {
  return parent !== child && parent.contains(child);
}

var parentEl = document.querySelector('#parent'),
    childEl = document.querySelector('#child')
    
if (contains(parentEl, childEl)) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerText = 'I confirm, that child is within parent el';
}

if (!contains(childEl, parentEl)) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerText += ' and parent is not within child';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="child"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty amazing! The recursion is cool. I'm wondering how the argument of the function becomes (inside) the object the function operates on. Might you have a link to more information on that?

Answer (score 21):

If you have an element that does not have a specific selector and you still want to check if it is a descendant of another element, you can use [jQuery.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

> jQuery.contains( container, contained )
>   Description: Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element.

You can pass the parent element and the element that you want to check to that function and it returns if the latter is a descendant of the first.

Comment: Pay extra attention to `$.contains` taking DOM elements and **not** jQuery instances, or it will always return false.

Comment: Another detail to remember: `$.contains` never returns true if the two arguments are the same element. If you want that, use `domElement.contains(domElement)`.

Answer (score 13):

Ended up using .closest() instead.

```
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    if($(event.target).closest(".CustomControllerMainDiv").length == 1)
    alert('element is a child of the custom controller')
});
```

Comment: On modern browsers this also works without jquery: `if (event.target.closest('selector'))`.

Answer (score 9):

## Without jquery

### `target.matches()` with `:scope`

If you want to see if the target element has a parent which matches some selector use the [**`.matches()`**  method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) on the target and pass the selector followed by the [**`:scope`** pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope).

The `:scope` here refers to the target element so you can use the in a [**`:where`** pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) to help you write out a clean selector.

In the following example we will match all target elements which are a decedent of an `a`, `button`, or `summary` element.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

app.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (
    event.target.matches(
      ":where(a, button, summary) :scope"
    )
  ) {
    console.log("click", event.target.parentNode.tagName);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button>
    <span>Click Me</span>
  </button>

  <a href="#">
    <span>Click Me</span>
  </a>
  
  <details>
    <summary>
      <span>Click Me</span>
    </summary>
  </details>
  
  <span>Click Me</span>
<div>
```

Note the selector `:where(a, button, summary) :scope` could also have been written as:

```css
a :scope,
button :scope,
summary :scope
```

### `parent.contains()`

If you are interested in seeing if the target element is a child of a specific element use **[`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)** on the potential parent element:

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

app.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (button.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button id="button">
    <span>Click Me</span>
  </button>
  
  <span>Click Me</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get your code to work by just swapping the two terms:

```
if ($(target).parents('div#hello').length) {
```

You had the child and parent round the wrong way.

Comment: `var target = $(evt.target);` so your code should read `if (target.parents('div#hello').length) {` and not `...$(target)...`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can use this less-known method to grab elements of a certain parent like so,

```
$('child', 'parent');
```

In your case, that would be

```
if ($(event.target, 'div#hello')[0]) console.log(`${event.target.tagName} is an offspring of div#hello`);
```

Note the use of commas between the child and parent and their separate quotation marks. If they were surrounded by the same quotes

```
$('child, parent');
```

you'd have an object containing both objects, regardless of whether they exist in their document trees.

Comment: This is a cool hack, but does not work well with elements without ids, or classes

Answer (score 0):

To know more background info on [Aleksandr Makov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485168/8930845), checking the below page might be helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

> **Node.contains()**
> The contains() method of the Node interface returns a boolean value indicating whether a node is a descendant of a given node, that is the node itself, one of its direct children (childNodes), one of the children's direct children, and so on.

It means, the answer is not using a reclusive function.