# Is there a way to know if the element is inside a table or a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a generic delete function that will delete a record and then delete the `<tr>` if the element is inside a `<table>`, or the `<li>` if it's inside a `<ul>`

The element can be in a list inside a table, so I need to know what parent element is closest.

Is there a way to find out this using jQuery?

Comment: Funny you should use the word "[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest)".

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753634/check-if-an-element-is-a-child-of-a-parent

Comment: @Blazemonger: But how can compare witch element is closest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').length) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
} else { // must be in a table
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest

In the unlikely event your element is in a table inside a `li`, you need to be more creative:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').length) {
    if ( $(this).closest('li').is($(this).closest('tr').closest('li')) ) {
        // then we're in a table inside an li
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    };
} else { // must be in a table
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/is

Comment: Would not work if it's in a table inside a li (pretty unlikely, but want to cover all the cases if it's possible)

Comment: cook something that use 'closest' and 'has'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest()` jQuery function.

```
function elementInTable(element) {
   if (element.closest("table").length) return true;
   return false; 
}
```

Another solution is to search for each table and see if your element is in the table:

```
function elementInTable(element) {
   element = $(element);

   $("table").each(function () {
      var currentTable = $(this);
      if (currentTable.find(element).length) {
          return true;
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

I guess it's not the best, but can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(/*query*/).parent().is('table')){}
```

or if it's not a direct child

```
if($(target).parents('table').length > 0) {
   //do something...
}
```

Comment: That will never be true, since tables contain `tbody` and `tr` and `td`.

Comment: But what if the element it's inside a list that's inside a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery.parents() function to retrieve the closest parent of a given selection:

```
$(myElemToDelete).parents('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Sorry, but does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers on how to accomplish what you want, but I wonder about the initial premise... could you pass the id of the container to the function?

```
<li id="li_0">Some content <span class="delete" onclick="deleteRow('li_0')">Delete</span></li>
```

This would give your function flexibility to work in any structure.  But, I don't know if that would really work for what you're wanting.

Comment: Maybe, but the code it's already there (The project it's 2+ years old)

Answer (score 0):

First,check whether the parent exist or not.

If it does,then check whether its input/tr or whatever element you want to delete and then remove.

```
if ($(event.target).parent('.selector').size() > 0)
{
    $("#elementId").is("input")//or tr or whatever!!!
         {
//your removal code
         }
}
```